# Is it possible to create point instances with different radii in Geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I found it useful to have a *collection* of *points* where each *point* has a radius corresponding to its index (first point r=0, second point r=1, ...).

Just to explain briefly for what I'm using that:
This way, after instantiation by an *Instance on Points* node, I know which point was instantiated. This is useful when I'm e.g. instantiating something on the nearest point of a point cloud, but need the information which object from a collection actually was the nearest afterwards. Instead of the final object I'm using these "radius=index" points and replace them by the real objects only afterwards.

My problem is this: currently I have a *Collection* of 20 *Points* created manually using this *node group* 20 times on individual objects:

[image: Radius point node group]

This is my collection of 20 points:

[image]

This *collection* is used e.g. here (red box):
[image]

What I'm looking for is a way to create a variable number of *N* *Point* *Instances* (!) where each point has a different radius corresponding to its index by a/within a *node group* (replacing the red box). So far I couldn't find a way to do that. Is it possible (using Blender 3.2.0 alpha)?

Hope it's not totally unclear what I want, found it hard to explain...

**Edit:**

Here is a simplified example:
[image]
It creates points where the radius of each point is the index of the nearest object (by origin) in *Collection* *RefObjects*. It is using a *Collection* of *Points* where the radius of each point is the index in this *Collection* (*Points*)

What I'm looking for is a replacement for the *Collection Info* node (collection of *points* with radius=index) leading to the exact same result (without using a *Collection Info* node of course).

[image]

Comment: I'm finding this pretty unclear.  It's probably overly simplified.  I think a real world example, complete with file, and what you want that you don't have, or what you have that you want simplified, would probably help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you replace points by points with radius, you can replace your **instance on points** by **set point radius**:

[image]

Comment: When I saw your answer I thought ok, but this doesn't work in my real setup. But it actually works!
My biggest remaining problem now is: Why do I always feel like a complete idiot when I play around with Geometry Nodes and can't see the forest for the trees anymore :-)
Anyway, thank you so much!